# Crystal Reports and Null fields

Tags: crystal-reports, null

I'm using formula by grouping records in my report like this:

```
field1 + field2 + field3
```

But when a field inside the formula is null (for example `field2`) Crystal Reports not groups records properly; So I have to insert in the formula a condition like:

```
field1 + (if isnull(field2) then "" else field2) + field3
```

But there is a method to tell to Crystal Reports that when he find a null value it must return a default value that I have set?
Or is there a method to '*initialize*' fields so that recognizes a null field as ""?

Comment: Process you followed is correct... what is your problem here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
TRIM(field1 & " ") & TRIM(field2 & " ") & TRIM(field3 & " ")
```

---

or

1. Select from the top level menu `File | Report Options`.
2. Look for the "`Convert NULL field value to default`" checkbox.

If this box is checked, `NULL` is returned as a special "automagical" `DEFAULT` value.
This typically will convert `NULL` to *zero* in formulas and running totals.

Folks who are using newer versions of Crystal Reports will notice an additional checkbox in *Report Options* called "`Convert Other NULL Values to Default`".

This checkbox refers to the NULLs being returned by objects other than database rows (i.e. formulas and running totals). Typically a combination of both of these checkboxes is required to properly fix a zero totaling problem. (Depending on back-end database and usage)<sup>[[1]](http://blog.marksgroup.net/2010/02/crystal-reports-dealing-with-zero-and_23.html)</sup>